# Update nested Templates Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to change contents dynamically. But the content remains the same. Seems to fetch first match. no matter what the template is. Does not work even with hardcoded file names. The code works as expected but the content cannot be changed.

**Main layout**

```
{{define "layout"}}
    <html>
    <body>
        {{ template "content" }}
    </body>
    </html>
{{end}}
```

**Sub template 1**

```
{{ define "content" }}

<h1 style="color: red;">Page 1!</h1>

{{ end }}
```

**Sub template 2**

```
{{ define "content" }}

<h1 style="color: blue;">Page 2!</h1>

{{ end }}
```

**The Go code**

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    path := strings.Trim(r.URL.Path, "/")
    switch path {
    case "":
        path = ("index.gohtml")
    default:
        path = (path + ".gohtml")
    }

    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout", path)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}
```

I have also tried to ParseFiles before Execute with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the result the client gets?  Have you verified that the issue is not that the content is cached by the browser?

Comment: The client receives <h1 style="color: red;">INDEX!</h1>, but the path variable is correct "index.gohtml" and "about.gohtml". Opening with either path in a different browser shows same behavior.

Comment: You are just passing `path` as a data to the template, which does not makes sense. Please read the document of `text/template` and `html/template`.

Comment: Nested Templates are mentioned once in https://golang.org/pkg/html/template. I cannot find anything that solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting the path after the templates have been parsed is too late, I believe.

What could work (though I'm not sure is the most elegant solution here) is using the `AddParseTree` method:

> AddParseTree adds parse tree for template with given name and
>   associates it with t. If the template does not already exist, it will
>   create a new one. If the template does exist, it will be replaced.

Applied to your case, based on the condition you would `Parse` the relevant template file  (sub template 1 or 2), and then add it with `AddParseTree` to `tpl`, before you execute it.

Comment: Any tip or link how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

At last I got it to work, but only when not following the manuals.

**Solution Part 1**

Skip {{define}} and {{end}} in templates. Weird...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Go Web Programming</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    layout level
    {{ template "content" . }}
  </body>
</html>
```

And in subtemplates as well...

```
<h1 style="color: red;">Page 1!</h1>
```

**Solution Part 2**

I found a code snippet with AddParsTree as Eli mentioned and here is the code (simplified with no error handling)

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    path := strings.Trim(r.URL.Path, "/")
    switch path {
    case "":
        path = ("home.html")
    default:
        path = (path + ".html")
    }

    layout := tpl.Lookup("layout.html")
    layout, _ = layout.Clone()
    t := tpl.Lookup(path)
    _, _ = layout.AddParseTree("content", t.Tree)
    layout.Execute(w, "")
```

I do not really understand why I have to disobey the manuals to get it to work. Any comments that enlighten me will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and soved it this way:

*This works for me with the `{{ define "content1" }}...{{ end }}` syntax, but you have to give your templates unique names: `content1` and `content2`.*

I made a package for handling the template stuff.

```golang
package templates

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var tmpls *template.Template

// LoadTemplates parses a template folder
func LoadTemplates(tmplPath string) {
    tmpls = template.Must(template.ParseGlob(tmplPath))
}

// ExecTmpl executes a template and writes it
func ExecTmpl(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, data interface{}) {
    tmpls.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl, data)
}

// ExecTmplTree combines and executes two templates
func ExecTmplTree(w http.ResponseWriter, outer, inner string, data interface{}) {
    layout, err := tmpls.Lookup(outer).Clone()
    if err != nil || layout == nil {
        log.Fatal("ExecTmplTree: Could not get a copy of template", outer)
    }
    content, err := tmpls.Lookup(inner).Clone()
    if err != nil || content == nil {
        log.Fatal("ExecTmplTree: Could not get a copy of template", inner)
    }
    _, err = layout.AddParseTree("content", content.Tree)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ExecTmplTree: Templates could not be combined.")
    }
    layout.Execute(w, data)
}
```

I then call the functions as following (in main.go or elsewhere):

```golang
// call first to load templates from the folder where your templates are stored
// you might need fit the file ending, too, I simply use .html for html-templates
func init() {
    templates.LoadTemplates("web/templates/*.html")
}

// write a basic template without nesting
func exampleHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates.ExecTmplTree(w, "content1", "messageForm", nil)
}

// write nested templates. here, index is the outer template
// and code is the inner
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates.ExecTmplTree(w, "layout", "content1", nil)
}
```